# area of n-gon of prime points

Tags: prime-numbers

Using prime points (2,3), (5,7) (11,13)....to a last prime point to form an irregular n-gon by connecting each consecutive point with a line and connecting the first point to the last point with NO previous line being intersected by this longest line, do you
think there is some n-gon of maximum area?  After this, all increasing last points will have a connecting line from (2,3) to this last point that will always intersect  some previous line.
As an example. I want to go from (2,3) to (59,61) without having this line intersect any of the previous lines connecting successive prime points.  It can be  done to give an n-gon with an area of 127.  Clarity  for this question would result if you drew a graph for the first 20 prime points to observe what the curve is doing.
A variation of this question arises when prime points are redefined as (2,3), (3,5), (5,7)...and one connects (2,3) to a final point of this form to give an n-gon having no intersections of the connecting line with any of the lines connecting the previous points.  Example of this is going from (2,3) to (41,43)
to give an area of 200; from (2,3) to (71,73) the area of 381.  In either case of how prime points are defined, do you think there is a maximum n-gon for each in which the connecting line does not intersect any previous connecting lines between successive points?

Comment: I do not understand your last sentence. And do you mean to rule out 'stopping' at a point like $(23,29)$? Because in this case the long line back to $(2,3)$ does intersect a previous line.

Comment: If you stop at (59,61) the line does not intersect any previous lines and you will get an area of 127 (prime!!!).  I made a careful drawing and found the equation for the line to see that it did not go above point (41,43): it was 0.3158 lower than this point.  One would have to find the equation for all such lines going from (2,3) to final point to see if any x-value produced a y-value below this line.  One can make a drawing only so large.  Has anyone plotted such prime points to see what the curve  does to prevent lines from (2,3) reaching any final point?  Is there a maximum n-gon?